# Move MySQL schema

Tags: mysql, data-migration

We have a Linux server that has been running our MySQL 5.1 server.  For a variety of reasons we have created a new MySQL5.5 server.  What is the easiest and most efficient way to move an entire schema from the Linux 5.1 MySQL to the Windows 5.5 MySQL database?

Yesterday I looked into exporting the resultset of the query as a csv and using the LOAD DATA INFILE command but that didn't work correctly.  The dates didn't import correctly, there were nulls where there should have been data, I didn't look too closely at exactly what was wrong, just could tell it wasn't right.

This would be a one time operation.

Thanks,
leslie

Comment: Look into mysqldump. You can specify a lot of parameters from the command line. http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/mysqldump1.html

Comment: I tried to be friendly and welcoming by starting my post with 'Morning' but then realized with the global audience I should be more general.  I tried to add "Greetings" but it won't let me...

Comment: Yes, Leslie, unfortunately, well manners are discouraged here. See this thread: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) to export your entire database schema, and data as SQL commands.  This dump should be easily imported into MySQL 5.5.

Comment: thanks, I accepted yours because it was just a little sooner than arnep :)  the mysqldump worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

For Schema Migration in MySql

You can simply Use MySQL **Schema Transfer Wizard** prvided by MySql
To open the wizard, select ->**Database**, ->**Schema Transfer Wizard** from the **main** menu.

Then  Read the overview text and click Start the Wizard to begin.

Choose your target and source MySQL connections. After choosing and testing your MySQL connections, click Next to continue.

Choose the schemas to migrate, and click Start Copy to begin copying the selected schemas from the source to target MySQL server.

Review the Message Log to confirm that the migration completed with success. Click Next to view a summary of the results.

Click Finish to close the wizard.

This are the whole process.

For more information Check the URL, [For Step By Step guidences](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-mysql.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysqldump` to generate a sql file with all your data, then use `mysql < dump.sql` to import.

Another way could be to just copy all your datafiles (usually at /var/lib/mysql/ all MYD, MYI and FRM files) to the other server. As Linux and Windows are both Little-Endian, this might work.